# Installing mysql causes Error 2002 error

Tags: 10.10, server, mysql

I tried installing mysql server a couple of times and I'm having problems. First of all, when I install it gives me a message that it's setting up and it just hangs. I can't ctl + c out of it, so I reboot the server and try to log into the db with

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

I enter my password and then get

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I restart the server:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
```

I try this:

```
$ aptitude search mysql | grep ^i
i A libdbd-mysql-perl               - Perl5 database interface to the MySQL data
i   libmysql-java                   - Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL     
i A libmysqlclient16                - MySQL database client library             
i   mysql-client-5.1                - MySQL database client binaries            
i A mysql-client-core-5.1           - MySQL database core client binaries       
i   mysql-common                    - MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mys
i   mysql-embedded                  - MySQL - embedded library                  
i   mysql-server-core-5.1           - MySQL database server binaries
```

When I navigate to the folder to see if the *.sock file exists:

```
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

it does not. I also try this:

```
$ service mysql status
status: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas? On my other machines installing mysql has been a snap, not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 2):

You've corrupted your packages I see. You said you cancelled the installation of MySQL server, which is the package `mysql-server-5.1`.

Try clearing your MySQL configuration and reinstalling it:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

Note that the first command clears previous settings and passwords of the MySQL database including the MySQL database itself. If you've just installed the server (as I can make up from your question), this is not an issue.

---

As SpamapS noticed, you can use apt's purge feature to get rid of the MySQL server and its settings. The commands for purging and installing follows:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

Comment: Might want to *purge* the package first before doign those rm -rf's. The files in /etc will stay deleted if the package is still installed.

Answer (score -1):

Does the file `mysqld.sock` exist? If not, try the following:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
sudo chown -R mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

Comment: Are you known with MySQL? The socket file is a special file created by MySQL server, you cannot just create it.

Comment: Yeah, i have done some troubleshooting MySql in my days. Actually i googled the issue and found an solution with the above stated answer. It's not that it would break the users system by creating that file. Anyway, sorry that I was trying to help...

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=276470&page=2 Post #17

Comment: @mount.cifs: that makes sense, removed downvote. But if it's a permission related issue, only `/var/run/mysqld/` should be created and chowned to mysql. Let MySQL server create the socket file by restarting it.

Comment: Hi,I tried this and did not work. I'm still getting the .sock error, as before

Comment: -1 from me, this is very bad advice I'm sorry to say. The mysql upstart job in /etc/init/mysql.conf creates these dirs as needed (it must, because /var/run cleared every reboot), and mysqld itself creates the socket file.